# How to start a program from web browers using php

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to make a open source kiosk like system. When the web browser starts all programs, it will run in the browser using PHP. I've found this link: [Program execution Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php). It's using:

```
<?php
  $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
  $oExec = $WshShell->Run("WINWORD.exe", 7, false);
?>
```

I was able to start Microsoft Word on Windows, but I need to be able to do this on Linux.
This is what I've tried on my Linux server:

```
<?php
  exec("/var/www/test.sh");
?>
```

But nothing happens. I know that `test.sh` works because I ran if from the terminal. I use `test.sh` to start a Python script. The Python script starts a text editor. I've tested the Python script and it works. All I need know is how to start the script from PHP on Linux.

Comment: What browser(s) do you need this to work in on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the test.sh owner permission to www-data
then add

```
Cmnd_Alias  RUN = /var/www/test.sh
www-data      ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: RUN
```

To /etc/sudoers then the php code

```
<?php
shell_exec("sudo /var/www/test.sh");
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try out [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php).

```
shell_exec("/var/www/test.sh");
```

Also, make sure that the executable "permission" is set.

Additionally, you have to run the text editor as the logged-in user (propably you will do this with `sudo` or so) and to set the DISPLAY environment variable to `:0.0` (or whatever is right for you). Example:

add this to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
ALL<tab>ALL=(kioskuser) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

(`<tab>` means that a real tab belongs there, edit the file by executing `visudo` as root)

content of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0
sudo -u kioskuser /path/to/the/editor/command
```

Comment: @user514584: Are you sure that you made it executable? What does `ls -l /var/www/test.sh` say? Are there three r and three x?

Comment: This is what it gave me -rwxr-xrwx 1 root root 11 2010-11-20 12:14 /var/www/test.sh

Comment: ok im lost can you give me an example of how it should be done with   sudo or so) and to set the DISPLAY environment variable to :0.0

Comment: @user514584: added an example (kioskuser is the username of your kiosk user, you will have to modify that in the script and the sudoers file)

Comment: this is what i get now sudo:no valid sudoers  sources found

Comment: I think the OP wants  to execute  a program on the *client machine* that doesn't need to be identical with the server?

Comment: @user514584: Arrgh! Many apologies. The line has to be added to `/etc/sudoers`, and you now don't have access to it anymore. To repair it, you have to boot into recovery mode like described here http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo . Then you have to execute `visudo` and to insert this stuff above the line I posted: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=5d8b9738f156948eb5c693f9d4be6029&p=8123624&postcount=3

Comment: @thejh I was incorrect. I misread the first example as client-side VBScript, which it of course isn't. Sorry

Comment: on windows i got it to work with Apache on my linux box im runing lighttpd